# Is 3D pose prediction directly from point clouds commonplace?

Tags: deep-learning

I've spent a couple of days experimenting and trying to find papers on learning 3D pose directly from unordered point clouds with no color information. This [paper from 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08942) claims to be the first that does it. The results are not encouraging for my use case and I'm not sure I agree with their methods (I tried it for my problem and got poor results).

Overall I'm surprised that 3D pose regression with point clouds would not be commonplace. Have a missed a whole section of the literature? Is there some fundamental reason why this hasn't been figured out yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "thing" here?

Comment: The most common informal meaning of the phrase. Image classification with CNNs  is "a thing" or it's "commonplace". Importantly, it's commonplace because it works well and is justified. Image classification with GNNs is not commonplace, and I guess there are reasons for that.

Comment: Do you mean 'task'? If yes, please update the title and body accordingly.

Comment: No I don't mean task.

Comment: Oh, I got................